# Getting 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' when trying to call sharepoint Lists Service

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint, soap, service

Th following code is giving 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException'

```
    public class SP_Access
    {
        ListsSoapClient _proxy;
        XElement _lists; 

        public SP_Access()
        {
            _proxy = new ListsSoapClient();

            //authenticcation
            _proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();

            //Define the parameters for the service call
            XElement query = new XElement("Query");
            XElement queryOptions = new XElement("QueryOptions");
            XElement viewFields = new XElement("ViewFields",
                                        new XElement("FieldRef", new XAttribute("Name", "Employer")),
                                        new XElement("FieldRef", new XAttribute("Name", "Address")));

            _lists = _proxy.GetListItems("Search Files",
                    null,
                    query,
                    viewFields,
                    null,
                    queryOptions,
                    null);
        }
    }
```

Is anything wrong with the code, or should I need to change any config. at client or server side.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException is a generic soap error, you need to wrap your code inside of try and catch to get the correct exception.

Comment: Getting same error after handling as well. I don't have sharepoint installed on my machine, has this to do anything with the error or error handling?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Fiddler, this will help you to see what's going on inside of Soap Request.

Comment: Tried fiddler, This is the response from the server. [XML Response from Server](http://inky.ws/g/j8) The request sent is as expected and no errors with the request. Thanks.